# Access HttpServletrequest at service layer, which is the best practice?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, http-headers

I need to access the request headers stored at `HttpServletRequest` from the service layer at a `Spring Boot RESTful API`. The reason of this is that I need to access to the `x-forwarded-for` header to get the original IP address of any received request.

First I thought that the easiest way to achieve that is to `@Autowire HttpServeletRequest` at the service that need this info, but thinking deeply about this I've been able to see that it isn't a good practice because I'm mixing layers.

The other option is to pass the info I need from the header through parameters to the methods in service that need this info.

I'm sure that there is a better and cleaner way to achieve that, but after searching I haven't got any better way to get this information to the service layer.

Does anybody know which is the best practice to pass some request headers to the service layer or the information that those headers contain?

Comment: IMHO best solution is pass the info I need from the header through parameters to the methods in service that need this info

Comment: Just put the HttpServletRrquest object end of parameters in your method.

Comment: why can't you only send the IP address as a string parameter to your method at service layer ! it's normal

Comment: Do keep the layers separate.  Extract the IP address in the RESTful method and pass to the Service method as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly due to autowired objects remain until you kill the application, you should not autowire them > [declaring-httpsession-object-in-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43991546/declaring-httpsession-object-in-controller)

On the other hand, even It is possible you should not pass the httpServletRequest object to service layer. The reason of using service layer is already "**layering**". You can use something else as a controller and that time servletRequest object will be useless. It should not be in the scope of service layer.

Finally if there is something that you need from your request which means to service layer an ordinary data, you can create a **parameter object** and pass it to service layer.